# Android Studio SDK Manager downloading into incorrect directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I recently changed my Windows username from `myOldName` to `myNewName`. However,  when I did that, the SDK Manager is trying to download files to `C:\Users\myOldName\...`, thus creating an error saying it can't find that directory.

I want to change the download directory for the Android Studio SDK Manager from `C:\Users\myOldName` to `C:\Users\myNewName`. How can I do that? Because without changing it I can no longer download anything from the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Tools-->Android-->SDK Manager,then click the edit button

[image: Image showing Edit Button location]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, go to your SDK directory and look for `".installer"` in each of the of problem components (E.G if you cant install/update `"platform tools"` look for `".installer"` in `"{your-sdk-directory}/platform-tools/"` ). Inside `".installer"` you should find `".installData"`, open with a word editor the change the path to whatever you want, save it, close any file explorers that have your SDK directory open and retry.

Hope this makes sense and is not too late.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43385617/installation-did-not-complete-successfully-see-the-ide-log-for-details-androi/43385729 mentions that you might be able to just delete .installData, but I didn't try that.